# Buckets of documents grouped by term frequency

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to segment Elasticsearch results in buckets, such that similar documents (with most matching terms) are grouped together (on an analyzed field) in the results. I'm not sure how to go about having aggregated buckets of individual documents this way.

Here's the basic mapping:

```
PUT movies
{
  "mappings": {
    "movie": { 
      "properties": { 
        "id":    { "type": "long" }, 
        "title": { "type" : "text" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, for example, if a query is done for `hunger` then the results should be grouped as buckets of matching documents with most number of similar terms:

```
{
    "buckets": {
        "1": [
            {
                "title": "The Hunger Games"
            },
            {
                "title": "The Hunger Games: Mockingjay"
            },
            {
                "title": "The Hunger Games: Catching Fire"
            }
        ],
        "2": [
            {
                "title": "Aqua Teen Hunger Force"
            },
            {
                "title": "Force of Hunger"
            }
        ],
        "3": [
            {
                "title": "Hunger Pain"
            }
        ],
        :
        :
        :
    }
}
```

In the above example, similar documents are grouped in separate buckets, based on at-least two matching terms. All matching titles without similar terms are still included in the results as separate buckets (e.g. bucket #3).

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked More like this query?https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html . You can also check clustering using Carrot2 algorithm. It might not scale very well. https://github.com/carrot2/elasticsearch-carrot2 . I am not sure if this feature is released yet officially but you can check locality hash also https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/20206